# ASP.NET Determine executed port number of site (C#, IIS, NET6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, port, .net-6.0

I need to find out the port number of my ASP.NET application. It is hosted by an IIS and I need to determine the port number (e.g. "7535" in example "http://test.com:7535"). Preferably I need to determine this port in the program.cs file of the ASP.NET project.

Is there any opportunity?

Thank you very uh and best regards.

Comment: Unfortunately no because I do not have a request.

Comment: Do you have access to IIS?

Comment: Yes, I have access to IIS. It would be great if I could determine the complete URL...

Comment: Should not be the url be available there?

Comment: The question is how to determine the URL hosted by IIS via program code...

Comment: How do you host the app inside the IIS? Inproc, outofproc?